# Dexguard obfuscation results in weird behaviour on some android devices

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, dexguard

I am using dexguard 6.0.26 to obfuscate an android library. In the config file I have the following options

```
-android
-zipalign 4
-include E:\\DexGuard6.0.26\\lib\\dexguard-assumptions.pro
-dontoptimize
-dontshrink
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*,!code/allocation/variable
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
```

Along with the usual ***keep*** options for my classes.
The library builds and my app that uses the library works fine on many devices, but on some devices (e.g asus zenpad 3s 10 z500kl , android 7.0), some strange behaviour occurs

- The library code uses the MD5 hash algorithm  and on the faulty devices I get the error Message ***java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: MD5 MessageDigest not available***, at the line ***MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");*** but on other devices the app works fine.
- Some blocks of code e.g *if..else* are completely skipped/ignored even though after decompiling the obfuscated jar I can see the code block in the class file!!

Just to make sure, if I add the dexguard option ***-dontobfuscate*** and re-build my jar, the app now works fine on all devices including the asus tablet, so I know for sure obfuscation is doing something crazy here.

Has anyone ever faced this issue and managed to resolved it? Any help/tips would be appreciated.

Comment: My only advice is to contact Guardsquare support. They're generally quite good at helping to diagnose problems (as you'd expect for the price). We've had quite a few issues, both while building and at runtime. Approximately half of those issues were configuration errors on our end, but quite a few were bugs in their SDK, which they fixed reasonably promptly.

Comment: Well unfortunately guardsquare told me that version 6.0.26 is old and I need to buy a newer version. Only problem is that the newer version is per package based licensing which isn't suitable for me, thanks though